# How Do I Use The KDiff3 Preprocessor Command In Windows?

Tags: windows, kdiff3

KDiff3 has the option to pre-process the files before diffing them.

However, the [examples in the docs](https://docs.kde.org/trunk4/en/extragear-utils/kdiff3/preprocessors.html) are based around sed and perl which aren't installed by default in Windows.

How do I use regex to ignore any line that contains `serialVersionUID = 20050617;` when I am on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy these utilities on Windows using GnuUtils, UnxUtils, cygwin, Windows subsystem for Linux and other options. There are ways to use native dos/windows utilities but the unix utilities are far more powerful.

Comment: Whilst technically this will work, I am looking for an option that I can use without installing extra programs into Windows as sometimes I am in a position where I don't have permissions to do that.